# Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow with JAVA 7 for desktop application

Tags: json, oauth, java-7, sample

My application is hosted with JAVA 7. Hence need to have code sample for which is samples is  with JAVA 7. 
I can see the code with JAVA 8 or above.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop